# Matches are played "alternatively" in odd-positon rounds and in even-position rounds

Tags: comparison

would you please take a look at the following sentence:

> Matches are played "alternatively" in odd-positon rounds and in
> even-position rounds.

I was troubled by this sentence because I thought it can mean either

Matches are played, firstly, in many odd-positon rounds and, then, in many even-position rounds; so on and so forth.

or

Matches are played, firstly, in an odd-positon round and, then, in an even-position round; so on and so forth.

Could you please explain which of the above is the right one? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a mistake in word choice. They probably meant "alternately", that is, odd-position followed by even-position, followed by odd-position, and so on.

Comment: Thank you, Jack! A quick follow-up: so assuming the sentence had used "alternately", then the first of my interpretation would be wrong.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Unless there is another  "alternative" mentioned in the text before the given quote, I think  "alternatively" isn't the right word. Then, with "alternately", you second interpretation would be correct.